# Springboot schedular run in multi thread

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, scheduler

I have more than five methods inside a scheduler. each will trigger a SOAP request and fetch data from the remote system and save to spring mongo DB.
I don't want these scheduler run sequentially. If one fails it will not affect other methods in the scheduler. How can I make each method trigger in separate thread ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling

public class Scheduler {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);
    @Autowired
    private MaterialRepository materialRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    //fire each 1 minute
    //method1
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void getMaterial() {
        //get data and save to db
    }
//Using SOAP Web Services , fetching the values from SAP and saving to MongoDB
    //fire each 1 minute
    //method 2
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void getCustomers() {
        //get data and save to db
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(); //single threaded by default
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that if an process fails the other process fails too? By default, Spring launch a separate thread for each Scheduled annotations.

Comment: Just tested. You are right.  failing of one scheduler method doesn't affect other.

Comment: Vote mi answer‍♂️

Comment: Did spring guarantee that if I am setting all scheduler method to start on 12 am morning. Does it all work parallel  ? or What is the best way to schedule each ?